# phpmailer error with long email addresses

Tags: phpmailer

I run a list of subscribed webmasters and recently migrated to PHPMailer.
I have my phpmailer script working fine. It takes values from my mysql database and send them an email but sometimes I get the **Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.**

After some tests, I found the error is displayed when the full email address is more than ***82 characters***.

As you know, working with email address of webmasters of seo micro niche sites can give me lot of addresses with more than 82 characters since their domains are very long.

Is there any setting to change for that? I dont know why its limited if 82 characters is less than 256 characters allowed for any email address.

Any help? I searched google and stack overflow for this reply but nothing was found.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using PHPMailer's `validateAddress()` method before trying to send, though it's used internally anyway when you call `addAddress()`.

The unit tests contain [a long list of valid and invalid addresses](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/test/phpmailerTest.php#L335) that test many corner cases.

I would guess that you are not running into an overall limit, but a lower limit within the domain name. Though the overall address can be 255 chars, elements within it have lower limits, for example each label within a domain (e.g. `example` and `com` in `example.com`) has a limit of 63 chars. 82 chars sounds like this limit plus a few other bits, like `user@<somethingover63charslong>.com`. If this is like the addresses you have, that's hard luck; You can't use invalid addresses and expect them to work. It's the addresses that are the problem.